# IIS multiple website subdomains on A record - mapping throws 404 error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosting with 1 IP, and multiple A records assigned to that IP.

Example:

IP of hosting:
123.123.123.123

This is how I have dns records assigned with domain registrar:

- 123.123.123.123 A test.domain.com
- 123.123.123.123 A stackoverflow.domain.com
- 123.123.123.123 A hello.domain.com

Now I have multiple websites in IIS. To have different subdomains binded to different websites all I should do is to bind subdomain:

http://puu.sh/gvznZ/fab84bde4e.jpg

But the problem is, that when I do this website on assigned port stops working, but when I visit a website with assigned subdomain like in a picture it gives me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fvOc.png

Do I have to assign more settings to directory or something?

**Edit**
Ok found out that http://bo.domain.com:777/ works. But how do I remove this port?

Comment: Are you using port 777 for a reason?

Comment: Yes I have multiple websites with different ports. I found out that http://bo.domain.com:777/ does work, but I don't want to use port.. that is the whole point of binding?

Comment: You don't need to use different ports. You can use port 80 for all, you just need to bind each website to it's correct domain.

Comment: So In case I have domain to bind to them, I can use them all on port 80, if no domain I have to use different port? Is that how does it work?

Comment: What do you mean "no domain"? How would you access a site for which you don't assign a domain?

Comment: Just write this as an answer, i will mark it as answer. got it done with your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple websites can use the same port as long as they have distinct domain bindings. You can use port 80 for all (and avoid needing to type a port in the browser address), just make sure you edit the bindings for each IIS website and specify the correct domain.